# Why is username to connect Cygwin's OpenSSH Server is <hostname>+<username> format?

Tags: ssh, cygwin, openssh

## Goal

My goal is to use the windows account username to open OpenSSH connection. I have a Win10 PC with cygwin. I have the PC with Cygwin's OpenSSH on it.

## Current Situation

Currently, I can establish the OpenSSH connection to the PC from my mac, via the following command:

ssh mypc+user1@mypc

Note that mypc=pc's computer name, and user1=window's user account name

But if I do the following, the connection is not able to establish.

ssh user1@mypc

As a result, I see this error Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive)

I have some experience with Windows' native OpenSSH but with that I could simply use user1@mypc to establish a connection. But with cygwin, I have to use "mypc+user1@mypc" to make it work so far.

## Question

Why with Cygwin I have to use such hostname+username format?
Can this be changed to more familiar username-only format via a configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin programs use the `+` rather than the `\` character to separate authority names from account names. Cygwin's account naming rules are as follows:

- Well-known and built-in accounts will be named as in Windows, without an authority name. Examples: `Administrators` or `SYSTEM`
- If the computer is *not* a domain member, the authority name is not used. Example: `Administrator` (not `COMPUTERNAME+Administrator`)
- If the computer *is* a domain member, accounts from the computer's domain are used without an authority name. Example: `kendyer` (not `DOMAIN1+kendyer`)
- Accounts from other domains use the domain name as the authority name. Example: `DOMAIN2+lynndyer`
- Local computer accounts of a domain member computer use the computer name as the authority. Example: `COMPUTERNAME+localuser`

See https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-mapping for details.